# Add style to element from user input

Tags: javascript, code-generation, css

I have a basic Generator for border radius, where the user types in the number of their choice and it inserts the number into the preview code. However I want to have a preview box that changes according to the number they have inserted. I am half way there but can't seem to figure out the last bit.

HTML:

```
<label>Border Radius:</label>
<input name="border-radius" id="jj_input" class="jj_input" type="text" size="2" value='' onkeyup='changeRadius()' />
<span>px</span>

<div class="yourcode">
    <p>border-radius: <span id="radius"></span>px; </p>
    <p>webkit-border-radius: <span id="radius2"></span>px; </p>
</div>

<div id="preview">
    <span class="preview_text">Preview Text</span>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function changeRadius(){
    var jj_input = document.getElementById('jj_input').value;
    document.getElementById('radius').innerHTML = jj_input;
    document.getElementById('radius2').innerHTML = jj_input;

    document.getElementById('preview').style.borderRadius = 'WHAT_GOES_HERE?' ;
}
```

Where is says "WHAT_GOES_HERE?", I want this value to be the same as jj_input.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('preview').style.borderRadius = jj_input + 'px';
```

We're simply assigning the value of `element.style.borderRadius` to that of `jj_input` and concatenating in `px`.

Comment: ahh I gotcha. I did add jj_input but didn't add `+ 'px'` . Thanks so much. Will accept the answer when it allows me ;)